# Set the value fo a variable in one jsp and retrieve in another jsp

Tags: jsp, jstl, jspinclude

In jsp A, I have this statement:

```
<c:set var="prefix" value="fe" />
```

In jsp A, I include jsp B and then in B, I do:
alert(${prefix});

And I get : `'fe' in undefined`
How can I get the value of the variable prefix in jsp B?

Comment: Is the `'fe' is undefined` happening in the alert dialog box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Maybe**, when the jsp is rendered, `alert(${perfix})` is evaluated to `alert(fe)`. The error you are getting is a javascript error because there is probably nothing defined as `fe` in your code.

What you might want to do is change it to

```
<c:set var="prefix" value="'fe'" />
```

So that it's evaluated as a String in Javascript.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the scope of the variable to request:

```
<c:set var="prefix" value="fe" scope="request"/>
```

Also, make sure you're using the include directive rather than the include standard action. The directive happens at translation time so variables defined in the including file are available to the included file but the include standard action actually inserts the response from the included file at runtime and therefore won't have access to variables set in the including file.  Simply put use this:

```
<%@include file="myinclude.jsp" %>
```

instead of this:

```
<jsp:include page="myinclude.jsp" />
```

Comment: Thanks. But 'request' is the default scope ...no? Also adding the scope = 'request' did not help

Comment: Nope, page is the default: see http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_set_tag.htm.

Comment: If it said: 'prefix' is undefined, i would have understood. But how can it say: 'fe' is undefined? What do you think man?

Comment: The directive <%@include> fixed the issue for me. I was getting this problem with <jsp:include>.